# Get-ChildItem Appdata folder across hundreds of machines. No access?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am currently working with about 400 machines within an organization and there is a file we are trying to determine if it exists on any of the user accounts on each machine under AppData.  The strange thing is when I run this script in my test lab each user account doesn't have a lock on the folder and administrators have full access.  In production each user folder has a lock on it even though the administrators account has full access?  I think that might have something to do with the below script.

```
$computers = Get-Content C:\Scripts\ListOfComputers.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    if( ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ErrorAction 0 -Quiet ) )
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer
        {
            Get-ChildItem "c:\users\*\appdata\roaming\microsoft" -Filter *.exe -Recurse
        } | select name, pscomputername

     }
}
```

Running this in the test environment works just fine.  However when I attempt to do this in production I cannot recursively search each user folder.  I can search in other areas like the root of `C:\` just fine.

For some reason it will not return any results and I am thinking there is an issue with permissions?  Is there anyway view each folder without modifying permissions?

Comment: If you do not have the permission to fetch the details, then you need to modify only. Make sure that the remoting and all other things are configured properly. Try to run smaller command like hostname and see if it is returning all the hostnames for the remote systems.

Comment: Running from a domain admin account and I can do other commands just fine. Also in the test lab is mostly windows 10 but production is windows 7.

Comment: Then I believe its a permission issue only. We need to modify then :(